# Application of the Frechet derivative

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, frechet-derivative

$f\colon U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differenciable at $x_{0}$ if there exist a linear transformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$, such that:

\begin{equation}
 f(x_{0}+h)=f(x_{0})+T\cdot h +r(h) \quad\text{donde}\quad \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{\Vert h\Vert}=0
\end{equation}

under this definition, I am trying to solve the following exercise.

Let $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})=\{T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m}): T\quad \text{is invertible}\}$ and $Inv\colon GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})\longrightarrow GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ defined by $Inv(T)=T^{-1}$.  Show that $Inv$ is differentiable and find $Inv'(T_0)$.

Starting from the definition

\begin{align}
 Inv(T_0+H)-Inv(T_0)&=(T_0+H)^{-1}-T_0^{-1}\\
 &=(T_0+H)^{-1}(I-(T_0+H)T_0^{-1})\\
 &=(T_{0}+H)^{-1}(I-T_0T_{0}^{-1}+HT_{0}^{-1})\\
&=(T_0+H)^{-1}HT_{0}^{-1}
\end{align}

However, I cannot identify who the candidate for $Inv'(T_0)\cdot H$ and $r(H)$.

I also know that another way to calculate  $Inv'(T_0)\cdot H$ is

\begin{equation}
 Inv'(T_0)\cdot H=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{Inv(T_{0}+tH)-Inv(T_0)}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}(Inv(T_{0}+tH))\big{|}_{t=0}
\end{equation}
But I can't find it.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is $T_0$? Any element of $GL$?

Comment: Do you know the Von Neumann inverse operator series (basically just the geometric)?

Comment: @FShrike I have no knowledge of Von Neumann series

Comment: How did your teachers show that $\mathrm{Inv}$ is continuous?

Comment: @FShrike They haven't, they just didn't give the definition of differentiability but no more.

Comment: Von Neumann series is that $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n\ge0}A^n$ if $A$ is a linear operator with norm bounded less than $1$